Gnome from 24.04 in 22.04
I need to stick to command line tools and glibc version and other libraries from 22.04
for development purpose at work.
But I would like to update Gnome to most recent.
Will comming 24.04 LTS give some easy way, to substitute packages, or there is another reliable way to get new Gnome?

You can use a virtual machine to test whether 24.04 would work for you. If it does not work, don't upgrade and stick to 22.04. It will be supported until 2027. With ESM, it will continue to receive security upgrades till 2032.
Don't mix libraries like glibc between different versions of Ubuntu, you will end up breaking the OS.
You cannot install GNOME version for 24.04 in 22.04 without breaking the package management system.
